# What does the term "shared variable" mean? How is it different from "global variable"?

Tags: multithreading, variables, memory, concurrency

The MSDN [documentation on writing network drivers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn641611%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#avoiding_false_sharing) uses the term "shared variable", for instance like this:

> False sharing occurs when processors request shared variables that are independent from each other. However, because the variables are on the same cache line, they are shared among the processors. In such situations, the cache line will travel back and forth between processors for every access to any of the variables in it, causing an increase in cache flushes and reloads. This increases the system bus utilization and reduces overall system performance.

I don't understand what is meant by "shared variable" here.  I know about global, local, and static variables.  Is this another term for one of those, or is it something different?

Comment: Exactly where did you see the term "shared variables" used?  Can you please quote a couple of sentences of context from that place?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn641611(v=vs.85).aspx  under the title of "Avoiding false sharing".first line is containing this term

Comment: Avoiding false sharing

False sharing occurs when processors request "shared variables" that are independent from each other.

Comment: Thank you.  I have revised your question to make it clearer what you want to know.  Unfortunately, while I know what MSDN means by "shared variable", I don't understand it well enough to explain it to you.  I can tell you that it's not related to global or local variables; any kind of variable could potentially be a shared variable, depending on how the code used it.

Answer (score 1):

In OOP, *Shared Variables* are the variables that can be accessed for more than one object. *Global Variables* are the ones with the greatest scope, because they can be used everywhere.

Source: "Programming Smalltalk - Object-Orientation from the Beginning," page 52

Answer (score 0):

A shared variable is one which is shared between threads. This is entirely orthogonal to static programme scope.